# How to get more protein without wasting food

Tags: diet, strength-training, protein, food

I know someone who is very fit, and what he does is eat 12 eggs without the yellow part.

That's too many eggs for me but i can try. However, i don't feel wasting the most nutritious part, sadly also most cholesterol full part, is a good use of resources and fair to people who are poorer than me.

so what other things can be just as good source of protein.

Answer (score 2):

The yellow part is referred to as the yolk. It's actually not as bad as the rap it gets, although eating 12 egg whites at a time is bit high. But I'll leave that alone for now.

A google search for ["cheap sources of protein"](https://www.google.com/search?q=cheap+sources+of+protein) will give you a whole flood of answers, pretty much all of which are cheap in part because they are whole or less wasteful. [A post from sister site seasoned advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/8332/24110) also covers it. Here are some common ones just for reference.

Canned Tuna - 25 g protein/100 g

Powdered Whey - 15 g/20 g although not a whole food, still cheap and effective.

Ground beef - 25 g/100 g (cooked)

Ground turkey - 27 g/100 g (cooked)

Chicken Breast - 29 g/100 g

Liver(beef) - 20 g/100 g

Almond butter -15 g/100 g - high in good dietary fat, but also high in protein. More expensive, but may avoid problems with legumes.

Milk 2% - 3 g/ 100 g - again, high in dietary fat, but also cheap protein source

Peanut butter - 25 g/ 100 g - same as with almond butter (high fat), but also a legume some might people do not tolerate as well.

A lot of this is compiled based on a quick review of [(Stronglifts, 2008)](http://stronglifts.com/build-muscle-on-a-budget-the-10-cheapest-sources-of-protein/) and [(Mark's daily apple, 2007)](http://www.marksdailyapple.com/top-ten-protein-sources/#axzz2xPxeVrvO). The calorie values are pulled from [FatSecret.com](http://www.fatsecret.com/), which will also give you the full nutritional info.

It is also worth noting previous questions [Protein: How much is too much](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/792/7660) and [Is there a maximum amount of protein the human body can absorb a day?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/6362/7660), and a general stroll through the whole protein category.

Comment: A word of caution about dairy as source of protein: some diary products have a rather high lactose percentage. If OP is worried about diatary cholesterol he should probably be doubly worried about high lactose levels. Lactose is a sugar basically, and as far as heart disease risks are concerned, I believe sugar is now the new cholesterol/sat-fat.

Comment: Yeah, forgot to mention the whole dietary tolerance. I hadn't really seen much regarding lactose being the new st-fat (do you have any links?). What I've seen is around the usual GI tolerance for both milk and whey(although the focus is usually on casein). Not sure if OP concerns about dietary cholesterol are entirely correct, Zod covers this in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Muhammad,
Eat the yolk part *(yellow part)* of the eggs; it's very good for you. The yolk actually increases the **good cholesterol** in your body *( [this](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/03/30/health-benefits-of-eggs-yolks_n_2966554.html), [this](http://www.cholesterol-and-health.com/Egg_Yolk.html))* as well as provide a host of other nutrients such as

- **Vitamin A**, which helps your eye sight
- **Vitamin B**, which is good for your brain, energy, etc
- **Vitamin D** for strong bones and good skin
- **Vitamin K** which helps your blood clot better
- Calcium, iron, phosphorus, zinc, thiamin.... *(you get the point).*

Unless the yolk's being used for something else, ***tell your friend to stop wasting food.*** You don't need to eat 12 eggs to be fit. 
 
Just eat 2 or 3 full eggs *(preferably boiled)* and you obtain the proper nutrition you need from it. 
 
Remember that you still need fiber, carbs, and other nutrients that cannot be gotten from eggs alone. So, try to eat a balanced diet meal. 
 
Eat fruits daily *(if possible)*; they satisfy you and provide you the fiber and nutrients your body needs. 
 
More importantly, ***you don't need to eat like your friend to be fit.*** Just eat right and exercise right. If you've got the time to eat, you've got the time to exercise. 
 
Perform cardio, lift weights, and have fun with your life :). 
 
Other good sources of protein include:

- Beans
- Fish such as salmon
- Lean meat such as chicken, turkey, and beef
- Nuts such as pistachio, cashew, and nuts
- Legumes such as beans
- Yogurt
- Milk and cheese

These are just some of the protein-rich food items. Search google for more options. 
 
Eat right and exercise and you'll be as fit as your friend :).

Comment: Why preferably boiled? Does baking the eggs destroy any nutrients? It would seem to me that baking in  healthy oil with for example chopped garlic, unions, bean sprouts or olives allows to easily add other essential nutrients and would thus be preferable.

Comment: @Pibara, Sure, one can do that. As long as it's not being fried and one can be consistent with it.

Comment: Why not fried? What would be wrong with fried eggs? could you elaborate?

Comment: I don't know if you're trolling *(hopefully, you aren't)* but **all fried foods are to be eaten as infrequent as possible** . For the reasons, a simple Google search will provide as much resources as possible :).

Comment: I'm not trolling. I understand the problems of trans fats with re-heated oil and all, but I would seriously think that if you take one healthy food (eggs) and fry it in an other (non re-heated) healthy oil, for example olive oil, the result would still be healthy. I find the good+good=bad something I don't grasp without explanation.

Comment: Even with olive oil, you don't want to consume fried food frequently. There's a difference between **cooking with oil** and **frying food** . Cooking with olive oil is healthy. Frying with olive oil is good for indulgence *(every once in a while)* , but doing so frequently isn't healthy for you. For one, frying mandates that the food is coated with oil. *Too much oil* is still fatty. If you fry your eggs with olive oil daily, it still won't be beneficial to your body. Same thing as eating a jar of peanuts daily because it's protein.

Answer (score 0):

Eggs are a decent source of protein, and there is no reason to throw away the yellow part, certainly not the cholesterol in there. Egg yolk is one of the few foods naturally containing vitamin D and dietary cholesterol has been shown to play a neglectable part in cholesterol levels. But next to that, the whole theory that claimed a causal effect from high cholesterol to heart disease has been falsified. Want to reduce your risks on heart disease: "No more sugar!".

But anyhow, next to eggs, most animal protein sources are pretty good. If you have a specific goal in mind you may want to look for animal protein sources rich in specific amino acids.

Try to aim for about 2g of protein a day per 1kg of body weight.